# SceneView camera preview as background

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sceneview

I'm working on app that should use `camera preview` as background for `SceneView`. I'm trying to set it like this:

```
scene.background.contents = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)!
```

Application already has granted permission to use camera.
But video is not displaying, and in the console I see:

```
[SceneKit] Error: Could not get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
```

What can be the cause of this?